# Error bars with different colors in one graph

Tags: error-bars

I have two plots in one graph. Each plot contains its own error bars. How can I color error bars according to their plot (i.e. red and blue)? If, for instance, I set the error bar color red, then I end up with red error bars even for the blue plot shown in the picture.
[image]

Here is the code I used

````
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[numbers,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,shapes.arrows}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    every axis x label/.append style={black},
    every axis y label/.append style={black},
    every major grid/.append style={gray!50,line width=0.4pt},
    every minor grid/.append style={gray!50},
    every major tick/.append style={black,line width=0.6pt},%thick
    every minor tick/.append style={black,line width=0.6pt},
    every x tick label/.append style={black},
    every y tick label/.append style={black}
}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{fat-}
{%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}%
    \pgfusepathqstroke
}%

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={red,mark size=1.5},/pgfplots/error bars/error mark={fat-}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}
             
\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\large}}

            
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline={([yshift=-20ex]current bounding box.north)}]
\begin{axis}[enable tick line clipping=false,
    enable tick line clipping=false,
    clip mode=individual,
    width=5.5cm,
    height=4.5cm,
    axis line style={line width=0.6pt},
%    axis on top=true,
    x label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.5),anchor=near ticklabel},
    xmin=1,xmax=4,
    xtick={1,2,...,4},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.5),anchor=near ticklabel},
    ymin=0,ymax=2,
    ytick={0,1,...,3},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
]

\addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=0.7,blue,fill=white}] table [x=x,y=y,y error=ey] {
x       y         ey
1       0.59      0.059
1.2     0.717     0.0717
1.4     0.844     0.0844
1.6     0.964     0.0964
1.8     1.088     0.0088
2       1.211     0.0211
2.2     1.34      0.034
2.4     1.469     0.0469
2.6     1.591     0.0591
2.8     1.708     0.0708
3       1.8       0.08
3.2     1.836     0.0836
3.4     1.67      0.067
3.6     0.874     0.0874
3.8     0.093     0.093
};
    
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=0.7,red,fill=white}] table [x=x,y=y,y error=ey] {
x       y           ey
1       0.519       0.0519
1.2     0.568       0.0568
1.4     0.779       0.0479
1.6     0.847       0.0547
1.8     0.945       0.0945
2       1.013       0.0713
2.2     1.141       0.0841
2.4     1.266       0.0666
2.6     1.355       0.0555
2.8     1.419       0.0419
3       1.512       0.0512
3.2     1.602       0.0612
3.4     1.685       0.0685
3.6     1.741       0.0741
3.8     1.851       0.0851
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the error bar color to blue by adding the option `error bars/error bar style={blue}` to `\addplot`. That is, for your plot with blue data points, you should have

```tex
\addplot [
  only marks,mark=*,
  mark options={scale=0.7,blue,fill=white},
  error bars/error bar style={blue} % ⟵ this was the line I added
] table [x=x,y=y,y error=ey] {...}
```

[image: A plot with red data points and blue data points. All the red data points have red error bars, and all the blue data points have blue error bars.]

Also, just a gentle fyi, if you load PGFPlots, you don't need `\usepackage{tikz}`. After all, every plot you make is surrounded by `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`, showing that Ti*k*Z will work just fine without needing to load the package explicitly :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @gz839918. I appreciate the remark on `\usepackage{tikz}`

Comment: I was wondering if you could tell me why only right half of the error bars at position 1 on the x-axis are shown, while the marks are fully shown?

Comment: @gz819918 do you know why the picture of the graph you uploaded is half of the size of the original picture I uploaded? I'd like to know it for posting my questions more concisely in the future.

Comment: @Gagik for your first question, only the right half of the error bars are shown at *x* = 1 because the left side is outside of the axis box, and is therefore chopped off. As for your second question, I've had that same wish many times! Unfortunately, StackExchange doesn't let you resize images  (at least, not to a reasonable size) so the only option is to just upload a smaller-sized image

Comment: Thank you @gz839918. I still don't get why the left side of the error bars are clipped at `x=1` but the marks aren't, they're on top of `y-axis`.

Comment: @Gagik oh weird, I didn't notice that. I guess in that case, I'm not really sure then.

Comment: Thanks for help anyway @gz839918